# Passing parent as child to a function c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

BoxCollider, CillinderCollider and PlaneCollider are all public : Collider, so
Am I doing something wrong or is this simply not possible in c++?

[image]

This is the code:

```
class Collider
{
public:
    Collider();
    ~Collider();

    std::string* checkCollision(Collider* _reference);
    char* type;
    std::string* tag;

protected:
    virtual bool checkBox(BoxCollider* _reference);
    virtual bool checkPlane(PlaneCollider* _reference);
    virtual bool checkCilinder(CillinderCollider* _reference);
};

class BoxCollider : public Collider
{
public:
    BoxCollider();
    ~BoxCollider();

private:
    virtual bool checkBox(BoxCollider* _reference);
    virtual bool checkPlane(PlaneCollider* _reference);
    virtual bool checkCilinder(CillinderCollider* _reference);
};
```

And this is the function that is giving me error:

```
std::string* Collider::checkCollision(Collider* _reference)
{
    bool collided;

    switch (*_reference->type)
    {
    case BOX: collided = checkBox(_reference); break;
    case CILINDER: collided = checkCilinder(_reference); break;
    case PLANE: collided = checkPlane(_reference); break;

    default: std::cout << "invalid collision type\n"; exit(0);
    }

    if (collided) { return _reference->tag; }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You still have to down-cast the pointer explicitly, because the relationship between the `type` field and the dynamic type are not known to the compiler. It's a convention you're enforcing in code. Just using double-dispatch is probably easier anyway, though.

Comment: Referring to a pointer as "_reference" is a bit confusing, since it's not a reference in the C++ sense.

Comment: Read about the "visitor pattern". (You're halfway there.)

Comment: Also consider using an enum instead of a `char* type` (although double dispatch is still better here)

Comment: Look at [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#:~:text=In%20object%2Doriented%20programming%20and,structures%20without%20modifying%20the%20structures) and [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch).

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) might also be used instead of inheritance. [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) allows multiple dispatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative to traditional inheritance (which seems only used to allow multiple-dispatch), you might use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
// Your shape structures
struct Box
{
// center, dimension, direction...
};

struct Plan
{
// origin, vector_x, vector_y...
};

struct Cylinder
{
// origin, radius, vector_height...
};

// The real collision functions
bool checkCollision(const Box&, const Box&);
bool checkCollision(const Box&, const Plan&);
bool checkCollision(const Box&, const Cylinder&);

bool checkCollision(const Plan& plan, const Box& box) { return checkCollision(box, plan); }
bool checkCollision(const Plan&, const Plan&);
bool checkCollision(const Plan&, const Cylinder&);

bool checkCollision(const Cylinder& cylinder, const Box& box)  { return checkCollision(box, cylinder); }
bool checkCollision(const Cylinder& cylinder, const Plan& plan)  { return checkCollision(plan, cylinder); }
bool checkCollision(const Cylinder&, const Cylinder&);

// The dispatch:
using Shape = std::variant<Box, Plan, Cylinder>;

bool checkCollision(const Shape& shape1, const Shape& shape2)
{
    return std::visit([](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return checkCollision(lhs, rhs); }, shape1, shape2);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Apparently it's better to use double dispatch. Which is different to write but not more difficult and same outcome.